# how to send outlook email from draft folder in c#

Tags: c#, outlook

I am trying to send an outlook email item from MAPI Draft Folder in c# but no success. I am still searching how to send the MAPI Folder (folderDrafts) Items, casting it to MailItem is not applicable.

Here is the code I used:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace nameSpace = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder folderDrafts = nameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderDrafts);

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)app.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
mailItem.BodyFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
mailItem.Subject = "Test Outlook Mail Item";
mailItem.To = "receiver";
mailItem.HTMLBody = "html";
mailItem.Save();
mailItem = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)folderDrafts.Items[0];
mailItem.Send();
```

Maybe someone can help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thank you @EugeneAstafiev for your answers, I already sent my outlook mail item but my problem is MS Outlook HTML message body with Table is not showing correctly in Lotus Notes. When I tried to Save and Send manually, means not in code, from Draft folder, and it works. What I am trying to do is to code that same way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create a new MailItem object if you just need to send items stored in the Draft Items folder.

Be aware, various Outlook items can be stored in the folder, not only mail items. So, you need to check out the MessageClass before casting the item to the MailItem class in the code. For example, in C# you can use the is or as operators. Also you can check out the MessageClass property of the item using the late-binding technology, see Type.InvokeMember.

You may find the [How To: Create and send an Outlook message programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/02/outlook-create-send-message/) article helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the following line:

```
mailItem = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)folderDrafts.Items[0];
```